# Ordering by a strange column with highest at top

Tags: r

I have an odd set of data with a weirdly named column, I want to order this data frame by that column with the highest values at the top.

Colnames:

```
[1] "budget"                "company"               "country"               "director"              "genre"                 "gross"                 "name"                  "rating"               


[9] "released"              "runtime"               "score"                 "star"                  "votes"                 "writer"                "year"                  "gross to budget ratio"
```

I want to order by the highest gross to budget ratio but I don't understand how to do that.
I also am having a hard time understand the order function and how to select what I want to order by.

Comment: You'll need to show us some data, just do `dput(head(nameofdf))` where nameofdf is name of your data frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dataframe by multiple column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is named `data`, you can use the following code.

```
orderedData <- data[order(gross to budget ratio),]  # ascending order
orderedData <- data[order(-gross to budget ratio),] # descending order
```

It will order your dataframe and stores in a new dataframe named `orderedData`.

Comment: I keep getting Error in order(-`gross to budget ratio`) : 
  object 'gross to budget ratio' not found but I get the same error even with the other columns

Comment: try: orderedData <- data[order(data[,"gross to budget ratio"]),]  # ascending order

Comment: Try `orderedData <- data[order(data$'gross to budget ratio'),]`, where you must change the `'` to backticks. You can also accept the autocomplete as you type `data$gross` and the backticks will be included. These backticks are needed because the column name has spaces

Comment: I actually moved to use the arrange function but this helped me understand how to select the data.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is probably from not linking the object correctly. You have to specify the vector within the dataframe in the function.

Try:

```
orderedData <- data[order(-data$gross to budget ratio),]
```

Also, I don't typically use spaces in my column names and I can't remember if it throws errors for that, so you may actually have to do with '`col name`' it as:

```
orderedData <- data[order(-data$`gross to budget ratio`),]
```

Either way, if you just type data$ and then tab, you can just select your column from there and it should do it correctly.

Edit: Backticks are needed in that format, thanks Gregor.

Comment: Definitely won't work with `$` and no backticks. Options are `data[, "gross to budget ratio"]` or `data$\`gross to budget ratio\`` to refer to the column.